# Numpy array broadcasting rules

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting

I'm having some trouble understanding the rules for array broadcasting in Numpy.

Obviously, if you perform element-wise multiplication on two arrays of the same dimensions and shape, everything is fine.  Also, if you multiply a multi-dimensional array by a scalar it works.  This I understand.

But if you have two N-dimensional arrays of *different* shapes, it's unclear to me exactly what the broadcasting rules are.  This [documentation/tutorial](http://www.scipy.org/EricsBroadcastingDoc) explains that: *In order to broadcast, the size of the **trailing axes** for both arrays in an operation must either be the same size or one of them must be one.*

Okay, so I assume by *trailing axis* they are referring to the `N` in a `M x N` array.  So, that means if I attempt to multiply two 2D arrays (matrices) with equal number of columns, it should work?  Except it doesn't...

```
>>> from numpy import *
>>> A = array([[1,2],[3,4]])
>>> B = array([[2,3],[4,6],[6,9],[8,12]])
>>> print(A)
[[1 2]
 [3 4]]
>>> print(B)
[[ 2  3]
 [ 4  6]
 [ 6  9]
 [ 8 12]]
>>> 
>>> A * B
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape
```

Since both `A` and `B` have two columns, I would have thought this would work.  So, I'm probably misunderstanding something here about the term "trailing axis", and how it applies to N-dimensional arrays.

Can someone explain why my example doesn't work, and what is meant by "trailing axis"?

Comment: This is a really good explanation of broadcasting, http://www.scipy.org/EricsBroadcastingDoc

Comment: could you add tag "broadcasting" please ?

Comment: The link in @BiRico comment is now http://wiki.scipy.org/EricsBroadcastingDoc
I wonder why it was moved to the *archival dump*.

Comment: why is it named broadcasting? It is so confusing just like the name "imaginary numbers"

Comment: Unfortunately, the link http://www.scipy.org/EricsBroadcastingDoc is no longer available at my time of the comment. I'm looking for a concise definition of the broadcast operation. The description at https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html is just circular definition by "broadcast" itself!

Comment: Probably this is the link instead: http://scipy.github.io/old-wiki/pages/EricsBroadcastingDoc

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Well, the meaning of trailing axes is explained on the linked documentation page.
If you have two arrays with different dimensions number, say one `1x2x3` and other `2x3`, then you compare only the trailing common dimensions, in this case `2x3`. But if both your arrays are two-dimensional, then their corresponding sizes have to be either equal or one of them has to be `1`. Dimensions along which the array has size `1` are called singular, and the array can be broadcasted along them.

In your case you have a `2x2` and `4x2` and `4 != 2` and neither `4` or `2` equals `1`, so this doesn't work.

Comment: In other words, the `shape` of `A` should be a suffix of the `shape` of `B`, disregarding any axis that value 1 (?)

Comment: if by disregarding you mean '`1` equals anything' and either `shape(A)` or `shape(B)` can be suffixes of one another, then yes.

Comment: actually, you can look at any array as being infinitely-dimensional of size `...x1x1x1x1x1x1x1x.....xAxBxC` so we have a lot of leading `1`s, which can be broadcasted as other ones. This way you can forget that suffix stuff, just say `1` equals anything.

Answer (score 4):

From http://cs231n.github.io/python-numpy-tutorial/#numpy-broadcasting:

> Broadcasting two arrays together follows these rules:
>
> 1. If the arrays do not have the same rank, prepend the shape of the lower rank array with 1s until both shapes have the same length.
> 2. The two arrays are said to be compatible in a dimension if they have the same size in the dimension, or if one of the arrays has size 1 in that dimension.
> 3. The arrays can be broadcast together if they are compatible in all dimensions.
> 4. After broadcasting, each array behaves as if it had shape equal to the elementwise maximum of shapes of the two input arrays.
> 5. In any dimension where one array had size 1 and the other array had size greater than 1, the first array behaves as if it were copied along that dimension
>
> If this explanation does not make sense, try reading the explanation [from the documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) or [this explanation](https://scipy.github.io/old-wiki/pages/EricsBroadcastingDoc).

Answer (score 0):

we should consider two points about broadcasting. first: what is possible. second: how much of the possible things is done by numpy.

I know it might look a bit confusing, but I will make it clear by some example.

lets start from the zero level.

suppose we have two matrices. first matrix has three dimensions (named A) and the second has five (named B). numpy tries to match last/trailing dimensions. so numpy does not care about the first two dimensions of B. then numpy compares those trailing dimensions with each other. and if and only if they be equal or one of them be 1, numpy says "O.K. you two match". and if it these conditions don't satisfy, numpy would "sorry...its not my job!".

But I know that you may say comparison was better to be done in way that can handle when they are devisable(4 and 2 / 9 and 3). you might say it could be replicated/broadcasted by a whole number(2/3 in out example). and i am agree with you. and this is the reason I started my discussion with a distinction between what is possible and what is the capability of numpy.