# Elementwise multplication with numpy.multiply

Tags: numpy, elementwise-operations

Let's say I have a N × 1 × 1 array `a`, and N × M × M array `b` as NumPy arrays. I want to do the elementwise multiplication:

```
c[i,:,:] = a[i]*b[i,:,:]
```

without iterating over `i`. The function `np.multiply(a,b)` seems to do the job. However, I do not quite understand the inner workings of this function when `a` and `b` do not have the same size. I know that when it has the same size then it just multiplies elementwise. I assume when they are not of the same size then it does some broadcasting to change the dimensions of one of the arrays but how?

Comment: Broadcasting is not straightforward at first but it will make your code much faster. Just read the [official doc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html) a few times and then practice. You do not need to use `multiply`, `c=a*b` will also work.

Comment: Have a read of this question too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11178179/numpy-array-broadcasting-rules?rq=1