# numpy broadcasting - explanation of trailing axes

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting

## Question

Please elaborate the answer in [Numpy array broadcasting rules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11178246/4281353) in 2012, and clarify what ***trailing axes*** are, as I am not sure which "linked documentation page" the answer refers to. Perhaps it has changed in the last 8 years.

As **axes** in `trailing axes` is plural, at least two last axes sizes must match (except sigular)? If so why at least two?

The given answer was:

> Well, the meaning of trailing axes is explained on **the linked
> documentation** page. If you have two arrays with different dimensions
> number, say one 1x2x3 and other 2x3, then you compare only the
> trailing common dimensions, in this case 2x3. But **if both your arrays
> are two-dimensional, then their corresponding sizes have to be either
> equal or one of them has to be 1**.
>
> In your case you have a 2x2 and 4x2 and 4 != 2 and neither 4 or 2
> equals 1, so this doesn't work.

The error and the question raised were:

```
A = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
B = np.array([[2,3],[4,6],[6,9],[8,12]])
print("A.shape {}".format(A.shape))
print("B.shape {}".format(B.shape))
A*B
---
A.shape (2, 2)              # <---- The last axis size is 2 in both shapes.
B.shape (4, 2)              # <---- Apparently this "2" is not the size of trailing axis/axes

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-91-7a3f7e97944d> in <module>
      3 print("A.shape {}".format(A.shape))
      4 print("B.shape {}".format(B.shape))
----> 5 A*B

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,2) (4,2) 


Since both A and B have two columns, I would have thought this would work. 
So, I'm probably misunderstanding something here about the term "trailing axis", 
and how it applies to N-dimensional arrays.
```

---

### References

- [Array Broadcasting in Numpy](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/theory.broadcasting.html#array-broadcasting-in-numpy)

> The Broadcasting Rule
> In order to broadcast, the size of **the trailing axes** for both arrays in an operation must either be the same size or one of them must be one.

- [Broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html)

---

## Update

Understanding based on the reply by @Akshay Sehgal. Consider 2 arrays A.shape = (4,5,1) and B.shape = (1,2).

```
A = np.arange(20).reshape((4, 5, 1))
B = np.arange(2).reshape((1,2))
print("A.shape {}".format(A.shape))
print("B.shape {}".format(B.shape))
---
A.shape (4, 5, 1)
B.shape (1, 2)
```

Firstly, look at axis=-1 and the shape 01 in A is broadcast from 01 to 02, because it is singular, to match that of B. Then shape 01 in B for axis=-2 is broadcast from 01 (singular) to 05 to match that of A. The result is shape (4, 5, 2).

```
print("A * B shape is {}".format((A*B).shape))
---
A * B shape is (4, 5, 2)
```

Based on the answer from @hpaulj, a way to simulate broadcasting.

```
print("A.shape {}".format(A.shape))
print("B.shape {}".format(B.shape))
---
A.shape (4, 5, 1)
B.shape (1, 2)

# Check ranks.
print("rank(A) {} rank(B) {}".format(A.ndim, B.ndim))
---
rank(A) 3 rank(B) 2

# Expand B because rank(B) < rank(A).
B = B[
    None,
    ::
]
B.shape
---
(1, 1, 2)

A:(4,5,1)
   ↑ ↑ ↓
B:(1,1,2)
----------
C:(4,5,2)
```

Comment: A leading dim is added to make (1,1,2).  Then all the 1s are scaled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trailing axes are `axis=-1, axis=-2, axis=-3 ...` . Broadcasting rules compare trailing axes as opposed to `leading` axes (`axis=0` onwards).

This is specifically for applying broadcasting to different dimensional tensors (say 2D and 3D tensors). `Trailing axes` basically indicates the direction in which axes are considered for broadcasting rules. Imagine lining up the axes by shape. If you `lead` with axes you would have something like the following -

Consider 2 arrays `A.shape = (4,5,1)` and `B.shape = (1,2)`

```
#Leading axes

A  04  05  01
B  01  02
--------------
No broadcasting
--------------
```

To consider trailing axes you would instead look at them as -

```
#Trailing axes

A  04  05  01
B      01  02
--------------
C  04  05  02
--------------
```

That's all they mean with the term `trailing axes` in this context i.e. start backward instead of leading axes.

In other words, when considering to broadcast a `(1,2)` shaped array with say a higher dimensional array, we look at the trailing axes which are shaped `2 for axis=-1` and then `1 for axis=-2` in the reverse order.

Comment: And because the rank of A (3) > rank of B(2), two trailing axes from B must match to apply broadcasting?

Comment: exactly, match or be 1 for broadcasting to apply. `In order to broadcast, the size of the trailing axes for both arrays in an operation must either be the same size or one of them must be one.` Hope this clarifies your question.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Wish your explanation is in the Numpy document.

Comment: Glad to help anytime.

Answer (score 1):

The way I explain broadcasting puts less focus on trailing axes, and more on two rules:

- match the number of dimensions by adding leading size 1 dimensions
- scale all size 1 dimensions to match

In that example, paired down:

```
In [233]: A = np.arange(20).reshape((4, 5))
     ...: B = np.arange(2)
In [234]: A
Out[234]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19]])
In [235]: B
Out[235]: array([0, 1])
In [236]: A*B
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-236-47896efed660>", line 1, in <module>
    A*B
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (4,5) (2,)
```

By the first rule the (2,) is expanded to (1,2), and possibly to (4,2), but that's a deadend.

But if we add a dimension to `A`, making it (4,5,1):

```
In [237]: A[:,:,None]*B
Out[237]: 
array([[[ 0,  0],
        [ 0,  1],
        [ 0,  2],
        ...
        [ 0, 19]]])
In [238]: _.shape
Out[238]: (4, 5, 2)
```

Now the (2,) expands to (1,1,2), which works with the (4,5,1)

Starting with (1,2) for `B` also works:

```
In [240]: (A[:,:,None]*B[None,:]).shape
Out[240]: (4, 5, 2)
```

It can add as many leading dimensions to `B` as needed, but it can't automatically add trailing dimensions to `A`.  We have to do that ourselves.  `reshape` works fine to add dimensions, but I think the `None/newaxis` idiom better highlights this addition.

This behavior could be explained in terms of trailing axes (doesn't have to be plural), but I think the two step explanation is clearer.

There are, I think, two reasons for the distinction between leading and trailing axes.  Leading axes are outermost (at least for `C` order), and it avoids ambiguity.

Consider using (3,) and (2,) together.  We could form (3,2) or (2,3) arrays from them, but which?

```
In [241]: np.array([1,2,3])*np.array([4,5])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-241-eaf3e99b50a9>", line 1, in <module>
    np.array([1,2,3])*np.array([4,5])
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,) (2,) 

In [242]: np.array([1,2,3])[:,None]*np.array([4,5])
Out[242]: 
array([[ 4,  5],
       [ 8, 10],
       [12, 15]])

In [243]: np.array([1,2,3])*np.array([4,5])[:,None]
Out[243]: 
array([[ 4,  8, 12],
       [ 5, 10, 15]])
```

The explicit trailing `None` clearly identifies which we want.  We could add a `[None,:]` but it isn't necessary.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the way of thinking. Match the rank by adding leading dimensions makes perfect sense!

Comment: Since the question was about trailing axes in broadcasting and I had accepted another answer, I cannot change but really appreciate the perspective on broadcasting.